# Limiting transition speed to only one property

Tags: html, css, transition

I have a simple square represented by a `div`. I want it to change its color on mouse hover, with a smooth 0.8s transition on both mouse hover and mouse leave.
It works. Now I want the square to change position when the screen is small, but without transition. You can test this code and you can see the position changing is progressive, but I want it to be immediate without transition. So how to limit the `transition` to only the color change ?

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: red;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  div {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the property to change in the transition like: `transition: background-color 0.8s;`

Also, you don't need a `transition` property on `hover`

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: background-color 0.8s;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  div {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **background-color** in transition rule. See:

```css
    div {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: blue;
      transition: background-color .8s;
    }
    
    div:hover {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
      div {
        margin-left: 200px;
        margin-top: 200px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

It's important that you specify your transitions.

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite the transition with 0secs and !important to ensure it overwrites it.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: red;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  div {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 200px;  
    transition: 0s !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="debug.css">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div></div>


</body></html>
```